# Issue with my new iMac

Tags: imac, fusion-drive, hdd

I have a new iMac (27" 5k, mid-2017, 3.7ghz i5)(new in box, hadn't been opened), that has a 2tb fusion drive.  I went through set up, but maybe I missed a step, because my drives are showing up like this:

[image]

The Mac OSX2 shows as being a 120gig volume:

[image]

At present, the system is only using the 120gb part, and when I look under Storage (when I do About this Mac), it doesn’t list the 2tb drive as being part of the system.  In order to use the 2tb, do I need to manually partition and format the 2tb part to make it viewable and usable?

Comment: What exactly are you concerned with here, what kind of problems did you run into with this setup?

Comment: (sigh)  https://eclecticlight.co/2019/10/08/macos-catalina-boot-volume-layout/

Comment: How big is the data partition, what is shown as free disk space in FInder after you boot the system?

Comment: "Mac OSX2" and "Mac OSX2 - Data" both say the same thing - Capacity 121.02gb, with 15.29gb free.  The 2tb is not showing up in available storage space.